# How Can I Know the Number of Points on an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

If I have the following Elliptic Curve:

$$E: y^2 \equiv x^3 + 2x + 2   \pmod{17}$$

How can I calculate the number of points on this elliptic curve $E$ ?

and how can I invest the following law which calculates the Number of Points on an Elliptic curve NPE:

$$NPE=1+p+\sum_{x=1}^{p-1} \frac{f(x)}{p}$$

Comment: Just do a search: for $0\le x\le16$, ask first whether $x^3+2x+2$ is zero modulo $17$, and if not, check by Quadratic Reciprocity or any other good method to see whether this number is a square modulo $17$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;f(x) := x^3+2x+2\;$ be a cubic.
 An [Elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve)
 $\;E: y^2 \equiv f(x) \pmod{p}\;$ is defined as the set of points $\;(x,y)\;$ which satisfy the congruence **and** the point at infinity $O$, on which an addition operation is defined  which makes it a group with the additive identity being the point at infinity $O$.

Thus the number of points $\;NPE=1+|\{(x,y):y^2=f(x)\}|\;$ where we work modulo $p$. The number of solutions of the quadratic $\;y^2=f(x)\;$ is given by the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) as $\;1\!+\!\left({f(x) \over p}\right)\!.$ Thus
$$\;NPE=1+\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}1+\left({f(x) \over p}\right) = 1 + p +\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left({f(x) \over p}\right).\;$$